# Android Fragment Layout is not replacing a view using Linear Layout

Tags: android, fragment

I am facing some issues for fragment in Android.

I completed a implementation of ViewPager using two fragment class with its xml layout, An MainActivity and An Adapter.

First Fragment : Linear Layout is Parent as well in second fragment, Linear Layout is parent. I have a button in my first fragment, i want to replace first fragment means switch fragment from first to second.

I am using ViewPager. Kindly Look on my source code.

PagerActivity.java

```
public class PagerActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    ViewPager mViewPager;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pager);
        mViewPager=(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        /** set the adapter for ViewPager */
        mViewPager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
       // mViewPager.notify();
  }

    }
```

PagerAdapter.java

```
public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        /** Show a Fragment based on the position of the current screen */
        if (position == 0) {
            return new Welcome();
        }else{
            return new Locate();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

Welcome.java

Fragment 1

```
public class Welcome extends Fragment implements GlobalInterFace, View.OnClickListener{
   private Button welcomeBtn;
    private View v;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_welcome, container, false);
        welcomeBtn=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.welcomeBtn);

        findViewById();
        setOnClickListener();
        return v;

     @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            switch (v.getId()){

                case R.id.welcomeBtn:{
                    Log.e("click", "click");

                    Fragment fragment = new Locate();
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.parent_linear, fragment);
                    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();

                break;
            }
            }

}
```

Locate.java

Fragment 2

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_welcome_pager_two, container, false);
        locateMe=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.locateBtn);
        locateMe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), SignUpActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                ((Activity) getActivity()).overridePendingTransition(0,0);

            }
        });
        return v;
    }
```

welcome xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/parent_linear"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/splash_color"
    android:weightSum="100">

 <RelativeLayout
     android:id="@+id/rel1"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="0dp"
     android:layout_weight="50">

   <com.rey.material.widget.ImageView
       android:id="@+id/welcome_Image"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:src="@drawable/welcome"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

 </RelativeLayout>



 <RelativeLayout
     android:id="@+id/welcomeRelativeTwo"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="0dp"
     android:layout_weight="50"
     android:padding="@dimen/universal_margin4"


     >

 <com.rey.material.widget.TextView
     android:id="@+id/Ready"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="@string/welcome_ready"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:textSize="@dimen/universal_margin2"
      android:layout_centerInParent="true"
      />


  <com.rey.material.widget.TextView
      android:id="@+id/description"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="@string/welcome_descrition"
      android:layout_below="@+id/Ready"
      android:textAlignment="center"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/universal_margin"

      />


  <com.rey.material.widget.Button
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:id="@+id/welcomeBtn"
      app:rd_enable="true"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_below="@+id/description"
      android:text="@string/welcome_btntext"
      android:textColor="@color/splash_color"
      android:background="@color/colorAccent"
      android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/universal_margin2"

      />
  </RelativeLayout>


  <!-- Your RelativeLayout Items -->

</LinearLayout>
```

Locate.xml

same as welcome layout only layout id is changed.

When I click on WelcomeBtn, the fragment replacement is not working.mentioned this one in my source code in Welcome.java

please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Your parent `parent_linear`is instance of `LinearLayout` if you want to put fragment inside this view you should change your `LinearLayout` to `FrameLayout` something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/parent_linear"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/splash_color">

//... your other layout goes here

 <FrameLayout
      android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And change following part of your code:

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
```

Comment: should i replace my parent linear layout which has id parent_linear?

Comment: @SupriyaPandey you can't add Fragments to LinearLayout ! Change it with FrameLayout.

Comment: Amir Kindly FInd My Steps:

Comment: I Again Raised a question. kindly look on it. I resolved that issues but if there are two fragment present in viewpager. and onclick of first view pager button, it replaces the fragment. but on click of device back button, it does not resume on its first position. How can It possible.Can you please tell me.

Comment: in ViewPager both fragment are present and you need to replace them with each other. I don't know what Exactly you want to implement

Comment: I simple replaces my activity_main.xml with

Comment: <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/fragment_place"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">



    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".PagerActivity" />


</FrameLayout>

Comment: But After Replace How can I resume my first fragment on slide of viewpager. please help me. I gave most time , but it is not working.

Comment: Fragment fragment = new Locate();
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_place, fragment);
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();

Comment: it's doesn't provide comprehensive code. see this repository from googler that use ViewPager in correct way. https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117509/discussion-between-supriya-pandey-and-amir).